# Knowing default clipboard manager

Tags: command-line, clipboard, defaults

There are many [Clipboard Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager#X_Window_System) for *Unix-based* Operating System but is there a way to actually know which one is being used?

I am on *Fedora 20* under *Gnome 3.10.1* and I know that I'm using *GPaste 3.10*.

But I would like to know if there is a *command line* which would ouput `GPaste 3.10` (except `gpaste --version` obviously).

Comment: I've been searching for a method to do this, I'm thinking it's not possible.

Comment: That would be unfortunate.. :)

Comment: Agreed, but it seems consistent w/ the modular nature of things in Unix. There are a variety of clipboard management tools, and there isn't any place that these tools have to tell the system that they're attempting to manage the clipboard.

Comment: I see the idea, let's just see for a few days if anyone else have some ideas, if not, I will delete my question.

Comment: Yes, sorry wasn't intending for you to do anything, just giving you some feedback on my searches thus far. I would def. leave it for a bit to see if someone else like Stephane or Gilles might have some thoughts on the subject.

Comment: terdon in chat shared this link which might help you understand how the clipboards in Unix work and why this Q you ask is likely not possible: http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html

Comment: @slm Thanks for that very interesting link, it does help to understand indeed.

Comment: @slm it seems like it's not possible. Thus I would accept someone's answer saying that it's not possible. If you don't mind answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing an extensive search I wasn't able to find a method for doing this. So it would seem impossible to find out what downstream tools are collecting the results of the clipboards in an attempt to provide a "management" facility around them.